# Django REST Framework: how to make a APIView/Serializer browserable?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Using `serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer` with `viewsets.ModelViewSet` works fine for CRUD, as described in the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/). Unfortunately this requires a `Model` which I don't have on the login endpoint.

Relevant code snippets:

```
# Serializer
class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField(min_length=8, max_length=50)

# View
class Login(APIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
    def post(self, request: Request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Some logic using LoginSerializer

# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
  path('v1/login', Login.as_view())
]
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use **`serializer_class`** class attribute in a **`GenericAPIView`** (or it's sub-classes) class

```
from rest_framework.generics import GenericAPIView


class Login(GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response({"detail": "HTTP GET Method"})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response({"detail": "HTTP POST Method"})
```

Comment: I just added it, but no difference. I don't even see the route `v1/login` when I open `http://localhost:8000/`. It's like it's not even considered. Maybe linked to the view or `urlpatterns`?

Comment: I have updated the answer, now it should work

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer but unfortunately it's not working. The `login` route is not shown in the generated docs. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The `url` field of the `serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer` just uses the `serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField` internally. Thus, you can do the following to get the same result:

```
# Serializer
class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='login', read_only=True)
    username = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField(min_length=8, max_length=50)

# View
class Login(APIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
    def post(self, request: Request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Some logic using LoginSerializer

# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
  path('v1/login', Login.as_view(), name='login')
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's unfortunately not working. No error, but I don't see the hyperlink for the login route. Any idea?